# Running `make` no longer minifies the CSS in /assets/css v.2.0.4

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-recess

Running `make` in the /bootstrap directory v2.0.4 no longer is minifying the bootstrap.css. Is there a flag i can set for the build process?  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I do now is once any changes to the less files are completed, I run make and then manually run recess on the two bootstrap css files with --compress true and set their output to {filename}-min.css.